Facing problem after restarting
I was installing python3-venv using ChatGPT. I don't know what problem occurs in GNOME desktop environment. I am also attaching the link of what desktop is showing error.



For the 2nd picture at the machine login: prompt you are supposed to enter your login name and not a command. If you login to your account, does the sudo apt-get update command then work?

You're supposed to enter first your username and then it prompts you to enter your password. Then you can either run commands or else try to login to your desktop environment with this answer.
